# É possível passar variáveis por referência no javascript?

Tags: javascript, passagem-por-referência

No PHP é possível passar variáveis por referência quando sinalizamos o nome do parâmetro com um `&` antes. E assim, a variável pode ser alterada sem ser necessário a reatribuição de valor.

Exemplo:

```
function fn(&$x) {
    $x *= 5;
}

$y = 2;

fn($y);

echo $y; // Imprime 10
```

E no javascript? Existe alguma forma de fazer algo parecido?

Answer (score 1):

Não diretamente. Mas você pode usar uma abstração, como um array ou um objeto, por exemplo, para que uma função possa "alterar o valor" do parâmetro passado.

```
function alteraX(obj) {
    obj.x *= 5;
}

var obj = { x: 2 };
alteraX(obj);
console.log(obj.x);
```